# EF6: Switching Identity On - null values for Foreign Keys in this same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm using this code to make EF6 migrations to add Identity: https://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/

For tables with Foreign Keys only for other tables -> it is working without any problem.

But for tables with FKs to themselves, I've got `null` values.

Example table (before `Update-Database`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Komponente](
    [KomponenteId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OtherKomponenteId] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Komponente] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [KomponenteId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Example table (after DB update, but without deleting `old_KomponenteId`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Komponente](
    [old_KomponenteId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OtherKomponenteId] [bigint] NULL,
    [KomponenteId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Komponente] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [KomponenteId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

UPDATE SQLs from migration (`Update-Database -Verbose`):

`UPDATE Variante SET KomponenteId = (SELECT TOP 1 KomponenteId FROM Komponente WHERE old_KomponenteId = Variante.KomponenteId)` - this works, my `Variante.KomponenteId` has updated values

`UPDATE Komponente SET OtherKomponenteId = (SELECT TOP 1 KomponenteId FROM Komponente WHERE old_KomponenteId = Komponente.OtherKomponenteId)` - after this, I have only nulls in `Komponente.OtherKomponenteId`

My migration:

```cs
public override void Up()
{
    this.ChangeIdentity(IdentityChange.SwitchIdentityOn, "Komponente", "KomponenteId")
        .WithDependentColumn("Komponente", "OtherKomponenteId")
        .WithDependentFkName("Komponente", "FK_dbo.Komponente_dbo.Komponente_OtherKomponenteId");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed this by adding `t2` to `SELECT`.
Fixed code from https://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/:

```
Generate(new SqlOperation(
    "UPDATE " + item.DependentTable +
    " SET " + item.ForeignKeyColumn +
        " = (SELECT TOP 1 t2." + operation.PrincipalColumn +
        " FROM " + operation.PrincipalTable + " t2" +
        " WHERE t2." + tempPrincipalColumnName + " = " + item.DependentTable + "." + item.ForeignKeyColumn + ")"));
```

So now SQL looks like this:

`UPDATE Komponente SET OtherKomponenteId = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.KomponenteId FROM Komponente t2 WHERE t2.old_KomponenteId = Komponente.OtherKomponenteId)`